# Calculate the amount of steps needed to go from any start value to any end value

Tags: logic

Suppose you're making a counter of sorts, you have both a `START` and an `END` value. These values may take any value that you want—for example `START=30` and `END=0` or `START=10` and `END=20`.

You also have a `STEP` value. This value indicates how big of a step you want to take to go from the `START` to the `END` value.

Direction is already applied to this `STEP` value. For example if we're going from `30` to `0` with a step of `2` we already know that we need to invert the `STEP` in order to count from 30 to 0. (Step would become `-2` in the formula `CURRENT + STEP`)

#### Is there a way to calculate the amount of steps needed to go from `START` to `END`?

Provided that both `START` and `END` can take any value (May ignore the fact that they can be the same.) and that the `STEP` can take any size too.

---

In a scenario where `END` would be any number above 0 (Let's say `30`.) and `START` would be `0` I can do the basic math. (Counting from 0 to 30.)

```
END / STEP = AMOUNT_OF_STEPS
```

However when the values get flipped or become more complex I get stuck. **Could anyone come up with a formula that would work in any scenario? For any combination of parameters?**

Comment: BTW, I had no idea under what tag I should place this question. If anyone knows feel free to correct me!

Comment: Your formula is incorrect, having for example step of size $1$, you have $31$ steps ($0,1,\dots,30$). Generally something along the lines $1+(END - START) / STEP$ should work. Also you say "However when the values get flipped or become more complex I get stuck.". Might be helpful to show some examples what you mean by that.

Comment: @Sil The extra $1$ may depend on what you consider a step (the vertices or the edges of the implied graph). I'd say that it takes one step to get from $0$ to $1$ with a step size of $1$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Valid point, in this case it seemed to resemble more of a counting of iterations in a for loop (based on names being used). But OP should clarify...

Comment: Let's say you need to count down from `10` to `0` with a step of `2` it would take you 5 steps right? (10 - 2 - 2 - 2 - 2 - 2 = 0)

I just can't seem to come up with a way to calculate the amount of steps that would work for all values.

Comment: Please see comments above. What you mean by step? In what context does this problem arise? In the case above, you can consider $10 \to 8 \to 6 \to 4 \to 2 \to 0$. If you count vertices, you have result $6$, if you count edges, you have $5$.

Comment: I'm writing a program that involves a timer. The timer needs to be able to count up, or down—from any value to any value. Every tick a certain amount is added to the current value (towards the end value).

Now I need to be able to display a progress bar. To do this I need to know how many steps it will take to go from 0% to 100% so that I can size the steps accordingly on screen.

Make sense?

Comment: In this case I think it should be the edges you are counting, so $(END - START) / STEP$ should work just fine.

Comment: I tried and it seems to work indeed! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of steps should be INT((E-B)/S)+.9999). E=end; B=beging; S=step size. If input S is positive, the sign of the function output will be the sign that the step 'should' be to achieve the task.

Comment: Curious. Why add `.9999` ? If I convert it into code and don't add the `.9999...` part it seems to work.

Comment: The almost-one decimal added is needed to round up if the steps do not evenly divide the distance to be traversed.